# How many ways are there to divide $n$ dancers into dance circles?

Tags: combinatorics

We have $n$ dancers, and they need to dance in circles. The order of the dancers inside each circle **does** matter. The circles themselves aren't ordered.

In the original question there was an additional requirement that the size of each dance circle is at least $2$, but I think that part can be completed later using the Inclusion–exclusion principle.

Comment: Have you calculated the answer for small values of $n$?

Comment: I haven't, but since the answer turned out to be so simple, I assume that would have helped my figure it out. Though if I would have tried small n, I would have included the second restriction, which makes the formula more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have 3 dancers, then the possible divisions are:
$$S_3=\{ (1)(2)(3),\ (1)(23),\ (2)(13),\ (3)(12),\ (123),\ (132)\}$$
The set $S_n$ is the set of permutations of $n$ elements. The permutations are written in *cycle* notation. Each cycle happens to correspond exactly with a circle of dancers.

In other words, the number of divisions of $n$ dancers is the number of elements in $S_n$, which is $n!$.